# how to add Expires headers to asp.net without changing settings in IIS manager

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, yslow

when I use Y SLOW tool on my page. it shows Grade D on add expiry headers. It shows few images and css files where there are no expiry headers. How can I Add expiry headers to them. I cant change settings on IIS Manager. Is there any other way. i also added the following lines to `web.config` file.

```
<staticContent>
     <clientCache cacheControlCustom="" cacheControlMode="UseExpires" httpExpires="Thu, 31 Dec 2020 00:00:00 GMT"></clientCache>
</staticContent>
```

but still no use. Is There Any Other Solution?

Comment: Not an answer to this but you can version css and images by adding ?v=1.0.x to the end of the file name that does some expiry, might be useful to you - but in no way an answer to this question; just wanted to share.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Response.AddHeader

```
Response.AddHeader("Expires", "Thu, 01 Dec 2014 16:00:00 GMT")
```